# Video Camera using Intent camera dimensions

Tags: android, layout, video, android-intent

I am trying to get code working so that I open the video camera application(this part is working at the moment) but I do not want it fullscreen. I want the camera recorder to take up half(or smaller) of the screen during recording. Would anyone know if this is possible?
I'm very new to android programming so any help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PICTURE_RESULT = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final Button B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button B3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.snoople);
            }
        });

        B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int VIDEO = 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO );
                finish();
            }
        });

        B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.camera);
                Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly controlling a device camera requires a lot more code than requesting pictures or videos from existing camera applications. However, if you want to build a specialized camera application or something fully integrated in your app UI, you can get an example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskSettings) or [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskOpenCamera)